# convert dates from dataset to yyyy-mm-dd in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have already written my codes and I am having good results except for the dates. My dates are in form 'January 12 2020' and I want to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd. Can someone please help me to correct the mistake i am doing. Here are my codes:

```
    Date = item['reviews']
    for d in Date:
        names.append(name)
        date = d['date'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        dates.append(date)
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', date)
```

the output are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Pycharmresult.py", line 95, in <module>
    date = d['date'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

What do i need to perform to correct my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must first convert your column to `datetime`.

```
pd.to_datetime(d['date']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```